# File not opening from google chrome android browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-contentprovider

We have an android app that opens custom file(.bcem) which is actually a zip file with **renamed** extension.

I have to open this custom file with a URI like this from **Chrome=>Downloads**

```
content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/downloads/demo.bcem
```

The intent filter in my app looks like this:

```
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.bcem" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.bcem" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.bcem" />
        </intent-filter>
```

However, when i try to read this uri using Ionic3 Filepath plugin like this:

```
this.filePath.resolveNativePath(path)
```

It fails with the following intent:

```
intent.action: “android.intent.action.VIEW”
intent.data = “content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/downloads/demo.bcem”
```

Then subsequent calls to ionic’s filepath.resolveNativePath( path) fails to give access to file on disk.

What could be the issue? Should I use content provider in this case ?

Any help would be invaluable.

Thanks!

Comment: add this in your intent   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Comment: It's obviously because ionic using terrible code for this (like many answers here on SO) ... YOU CANNOT ALWAYS GET A PATH FROM URI

Comment: @Selvin what could be the workaround ?

Comment: Write custom plugin

Comment: @Selvin Sure. does the solution for this has to do something with content provider or something? I could write my own plugin for sure. But i need to know how to solve this.